# Intregrate Xpage Tool with LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, xpages, xpages-ssjs

We are working is an simple Xpage solution. The goal for this tool is to get personal information(Full Name and Company) from our LDAP and the other functionality is to change the password (password reset).
This is my java class

```
package com.mycompany.utils;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.constants.LdapSecurityConstants;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.cursor.CursorException;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.cursor.EntryCursor;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Attribute;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultModification;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Entry;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Modification;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.ModificationOperation;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapAuthenticationException;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapException;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.SearchScope;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.password.PasswordUtil;
import org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapConnection;
import org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection;
public class LDAP  {

/** The connection pool to use ldap connections from */
LdapConnection connection;

 /** The LDAP schema attribute name for first name. Default is givenName. */
private boolean found = false;
/** The LDAP schema attribute name for first name. Default is givenName. */
private String firstNameAttr = "FirstName";
/** The LDAP schema attribute name for last name. Default is sn. */
private String lastNameAttr = "LastName";
/** THe LDAP schema attribute name for DistinguishedName. */
private String terDistinguishedNameAttr = "DistinguishedName";
/** THe LDAP schema attribute name for userPassword. */
private byte[] userPasswordAttr = null;
/** THe LDAP schema attribute name for terCustCompanyName. */
private String terCustCompanyNameAttr = null;

/** Default constructor */
public LDAP() {
    try{
        System.out.println("Line 42");
        //this.connection = new LdapNetworkConnection("nordique.corp.mycompany.com",389);
        this.connection = new LdapNetworkConnection("qa.ldap.mycompany.com",389);
        this.connection.bind("cn=root", "xxxxxxxx");
        System.out.println("Line 46");
        System.out.println(this.connection.isConnected());
    } catch (LdapAuthenticationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("LDAP wrong Credentials");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (LdapException e) {
        System.out.println("LDAP Exception");
        //System.exit(0);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //System.exit(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Method delegated to from searchForUID which connects to LDAP and populates internal variables for
 * givenName, sn, and mail.
 * 
 * @param userInfo the UID to search.
 */
public void searchForUID(String userInfo) {
    this.setFound(false);
    this.setFirstNameAttr("");
    this.setLastNameAttr("");
    this.setTerDistinguishedNameAttr("");
    this.setUserPassword("##".getBytes());
    this.setTerCustCompanyName("");

    try {
        EntryCursor cursor = this.connection.search( "ou=employees,dc=mycompany,dc=COM", "(&(objectclass=person)(uid="+userInfo+"*))", SearchScope.SUBTREE );

        if (cursor.next()) {
            Entry record = cursor.get();
            //System.out.println("Record:"+record.toString());
            this.setFound(true);
            Attribute givenName = record.get("givenName");
            Attribute sn = record.get("sn");
            Attribute terDistinguishedName = record.get("terDistinguishedName");
            Attribute userPassword = record.get("userPassword");
            Attribute terCustCompanyName = record.get("cSiteName");
            if ( givenName != null)
            {
                this.setFirstNameAttr(givenName.getString());
            }
            if (sn != null)
            {
                this.setLastNameAttr(sn.getString());
            }
            if (terDistinguishedName != null)
            {
                this.setTerDistinguishedNameAttr(terDistinguishedName.getString());
            }
            if (userPassword != null)
            {
              this.setUserPassword(userPassword.get().getBytes());
            }
            if (terCustCompanyName != null)
            {
                this.setTerCustCompanyName(terCustCompanyName.getString());
            }
        }

        if (cursor.next()) {
            System.out.println("found two matches for the user; " + userInfo);
        }

        cursor.close();

    } catch (CursorException e) {

        System.out.println("Cursor Exception: " + e);

    } catch (LdapException e) {

        System.out.println("LDAP Exception: " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("IO Exception: " + e);

    } 
}

protected void closeConnection(){
    try {
        this.connection.close();
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("LDAP Exception: " + e);
    }
}

public boolean modifyAttribute(String Attribute, String newValue){
    Modification replaceGn = new DefaultModification( ModificationOperation.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, Attribute, newValue );

    boolean status = false;
    try {
        this.connection.modify( this.getTerDistinguishedNameAttr(), replaceGn );
        status = true;
    } catch (LdapException e) {
        System.out.println("Modification fail");
    }
    return status;
}

public boolean modifyPasswordAttribute(byte[] newPassword){
    Modification replaceGn = new DefaultModification(ModificationOperation.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, "userPassword", PasswordUtil.createStoragePassword(newPassword, LdapSecurityConstants.HASH_METHOD_SHA256));
    boolean status = false;
    try {
        this.connection.modify( this.getTerDistinguishedNameAttr(), replaceGn );
        status = true;
    } catch (LdapException e) {
        System.out.println("Modification fail");
    }
    return status;
}

/**
 * Returns the found status. This is the status of the ObjectClass.
 * 
 * @return the status.
 */
public boolean getFound() {
    return found;
}
/**
 * Sets the found status. This is the status of the ObjectClass.
 *
 * @param status the Found to set
 */
public void setFound(boolean newFound) {
    this.found = newFound;
}

/**
 * Returns the terCustCompanyNameAttr field. This is the LDAP schema attribute of the ObjectClass to get terCustCompanyName.
 * 
 * @return the terCustCompanyNameAttr field.
 */
public String getTerCustCompanyName() {
    return terCustCompanyNameAttr;
}
/**
 * Sets the terCustCompanyNameAttr field. This is the LDAP schema attribute of the ObjectClass to get terCustCompanyName.
 *
 * @param terCustCompanyName the terCustCompanyNameAttr to set
 */
public void setTerCustCompanyName(String terCustCompanyName) {
    this.terCustCompanyNameAttr = terCustCompanyName;
}
/**
 * Returns the userPasswordAttr field. This is the LDAP schema attribute of the ObjectClass to get password.
 * 
 * @return the userPasswordAttr field.
 */
public byte[] getUserPassword() {
    return userPasswordAttr;
}
/**
 * Sets the userPasswordAttr field. This is the LDAP schema attribute of the ObjectClass to get user password.
 *
 * @param userPassword the userPasswordAttr to set
 */
public void setUserPassword(byte[] userPassword) {
    this.userPasswordAttr = userPassword;
}
/**
 * Returns the firstNameAttr field. This is the LDAP schema attribute of the ObjectClass to get first name.
 * 
 * @return the firstNameAttr field.
 */
public String getFirstNameAttr() {
    return firstNameAttr;
}
/**
 * Sets the firstNameAttr field. This is the LDAP schema attribute of the ObjectClass to get first name.
 * 
 * @param firstNameAttr the firstNameAttr to set.
 */
public void setFirstNameAttr(String firstNameAttr) {
    this.firstNameAttr = firstNameAttr;
}
/**
 * Returns the lastNameAttr field. This is the LDAP schema attribute of the ObjectClass to get last name.
 * 
 * @return the lastNameAttr field.
 */
public String getLastNameAttr() {
    return lastNameAttr;
}
/**
 * Sets the lastNameAttr field. This is the LDAP schema attribute of the ObjectClass to get last name.
 *
 * @param lastNameAttr the lastNameAttr to set
 */
public void setLastNameAttr(String lastNameAttr) {
    this.lastNameAttr = lastNameAttr;
}
/**
 * Returns the terDistinguishedNameAttr. This is the LDAP schema attribute of the ObjectClass to get email.
 * 
 * @return the terDistinguishedNameAttr.
 */
public String getTerDistinguishedNameAttr() {
    return terDistinguishedNameAttr;
}
/**
 * Sets the terDistinguishedNameAttr. This is the LDAP schema attribute of the ObjectClass to get email.
 * 
 * @param terDistinguishedNameAttr the terDistinguishedNameAttr. This is the LDAP schema attribute of the ObjectClass to get email.
 */
public void setTerDistinguishedNameAttr(String terDistinguishedNameAttr) {
    this.terDistinguishedNameAttr = terDistinguishedNameAttr;
}
```

}

In the faces-config code we define

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>emailBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.ibm.xsp.utils.EmailBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>debugMode</property-name>
      <value>true</value>
    </managed-property>
  </managed-bean>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>LDAP</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.mycompany.utils.LDAP</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
  <!--AUTOGEN-START-BUILDER: Automatically generated by IBM Domino Designer. Do not modify.-->
  <!--AUTOGEN-END-BUILDER: End of automatically generated section-->
</faces-config>
```

In the Xpage I defined one field and one button (this button will use the jave class to get information from the LDAP structure)

The button contains the below code

```
importPackage(com.mycompany.utils);
var UID = document1.getItemValueString("UID");

print(" ");
print(" ");
print("From xpages");

try{
    var ldapConnection = new LDAP();
}catch(e){
    print("Error generating dynamic LDAP: " + e.toString());
}

print("+=========================================1");
print (UID);
/*ldapConnection.searchForUID(UID);
if(ldapConnection.getFound()){
    print("User :"+ldapConnection.getFirstNameAttr()+" "+ldapConnection.getLastNameAttr());
    print("Company :"+ldapConnection.getTerCustCompanyName());
    print("Passsword :"+new String(ldapConnection.getUserPassword(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return ldapConnection.getTerCustCompanyName();

}else{
    print("user not found!");
}*/

print("+=========================================2");
print(" ");
print(" ");
print("END xpages");
```

Finally, when we execute the button we receives the below message in the console.

```
[1434:000A-0AF0] 05/18/2017 12:54:02 PM  HTTP JVM:  
[1434:000A-0AF0] 05/18/2017 12:54:02 PM  HTTP JVM:  
[1434:000A-0AF0] 05/18/2017 12:54:02 PM  HTTP JVM: From xpages
[1434:000A-0AF0] 05/18/2017 12:54:05 PM  HTTP JVM: Line 42
[1434:0047-095C] 05/18/2017 12:54:05 PM  HTTP JVM: Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-1" 
[1434:0048-095C] 05/18/2017 12:54:05 PM  HTTP JVM: java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext not initialized for the thread
[1434:004A-095C] 05/18/2017 12:54:05 PM  HTTP JVM:  at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.getCurrent(NotesContext.java:123)
[1434:004C-095C] 05/18/2017 12:54:05 PM  HTTP JVM:  at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:416)
[1434:004E-095C] 05/18/2017 12:54:05 PM  HTTP JVM:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809)
[1434:0050-095C] 05/18/2017 12:54:05 PM  HTTP JVM:  at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:56)
[1434:0052-095C] 05/18/2017 12:54:05 PM  HTTP JVM:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
[1434:0054-095C] 05/18/2017 12:54:05 PM  HTTP JVM:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[1434:0056-095C] 05/18/2017 12:54:05 PM  HTTP JVM:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
[1434:000A-0AF0] 05/18/2017 12:54:35 PM  HTTP JVM: LDAP Exceptionorg.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.exception.InvalidConnectionException: Cannot connect on the server, the connection is null
[1434:000A-0AF0] 05/18/2017 12:54:35 PM  HTTP JVM: +=========================================1
[1434:000A-0AF0] 05/18/2017 12:54:35 PM  HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
[1434:000A-0AF0] 05/18/2017 12:54:35 PM  HTTP JVM: CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in E:/notes/data/domino/workspace/logs
[1434:000C-143C] 05/18/2017 12:54:37 PM  HTTP JVM: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in E:/notes/data/domino/workspace/logs
```

Thanks for your help.
Best Regards

Comment: Can you connect to ldap from your qa server?  This line seems to say not: LDAP Exceptionorg.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.exception.InvalidConnectionException: Cannot connect on the server, the connection is null

Comment: Is the `cn=root` a dummy value for public posting ? If not, the binddn used to connect on a LDAP Directory needs to be in the DIT, ie. here it could be : `cn=root,dc=MYCOMPANY,dc=COM`

Comment: Hi Rob and Esteban for your answer
I would like to mention something, the Java process was tested and worked correctly. When we try to import the clases and uses into the XPage page does not work

Comment: The Apache LDAP library appears to be external, where did you put the JAR file it's wrapped with ? The error could be related to some kind of security condition preventing network access, caused by the security context allowed by where the JAR is located, perhaps.

Comment: Hi Simon... The process works out of the Xpage. The problem is when we incorporate the java class and try to use the class in the Xpage.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Mina creates a new thread for the LDAP connection, but uses the classloader of the XPages engine. When a new thread is created, this classloader checks the existence of the NotesContext, which is not initialized for the new thread. That's why it fails.

Comment: Thanks Sven; I'm new with Java, what is your suggestion to overcome this error?

Comment: I think the easiest way to solve your problem is to use an other LDAP Java library.